# Is there any Google API to get the Google Cloud Platform account information?

Tags: api, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I would like to retrieve the credit amount information of a GCP account via an API, is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) gives you an overview of all the available APIs.

Given that credit information is linked to a billing account, you are probably not interested in an [account/user API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/user/), but more likely in the [billing API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/billing/cloudbilling/v1/).

Unfortunately it is not possible to get credit amount information with this API (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/)), from what I see, you can only see the relationship between projects and billing accounts and check if a billing account is enabled or not.